# Copy & Paste format from Excel into Word or Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, paste

Recently, when I copy seven digit numbers from Excel and paste them into Outlook or Word, it pastes them as scientific notation and not as the seven digit numbers that I see them in Excel.  I have tried changing format in Excel from "Number" type to "Text" or "General" but it does not seem to matter.

When I paste, I can right click and choose several different methods of pasting, but the only two that preserve the numbers are paste-as-image (which defeats the purpose) and paste-as-text (which eliminates the table format in the destination application).

How can I paste in these numbers and not have them go into scientific notation?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the Paste options? Does it set to “Keep Source Formatting”？

Answer (score 1):

Happened with me once...for me pasting into notepad first did the trick.
Also try Ctrl + V in word

Which version of word and excel are you using are they both same ?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions for you to try out:

1) Copy from origin cell and paste into any other unused cell via *paste-as-value*, then copy and paste from that cell to desired external program.

2) Use, e.g., `=text(a1,"0,000,000")` to format the cell (can also try step 1 afterwards)

3) Try custom formatting through the context menu (Ctrl + 1) and use, e.g., `0,000,000`